# bash brace expansion based on variable content not working

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

how can i make bash expand whatever it finds in a variable i pass to mkdir?
so far i've tried using `eval` and `bash -c`, but nothing seems to work

```
LEVEL_1=1,2,3
LEVEL_2=a,b,c

DATA_L1="/tmp/{$LEVEL_1}"
DATA_L2="$DATA_L1/{$LEVEL_2}"

for LINE in $(cat file.txt) ; do
  #"cat" here returns values like 
  #$DATA_L2/yy/data

  mkdir -pv $LINE #it actually contains e.g. this $DATA_L2/yy/data
done
```

i would expect that this will expand to

```
mkdir -p /tmp/1/a/yy/data
mkdir -p /tmp/2/a/yy/data
mkdir -p /tmp/3/a/yy/data
mkdir -p /tmp/1/b/yy/data
mkdir -p /tmp/2/b/yy/data
mkdir -p /tmp/3/b/yy/data
mkdir -p /tmp/1/c/yy/data
mkdir -p /tmp/2/c/yy/data
mkdir -p /tmp/3/c/yy/data
```

Comment: You're not using the variable `$LINE` in the body of your loop. What exactly do you expect to happen here?

Comment: Brace expansions occur *before* parameter expansions. Also, how are you using `LINE`, if at all? Are you writing `mkdir $LINE` and expecting recursive parameter expansions?

Comment: Ignoring `file.txt` for the moment, you can write `for d in /tmp/{1,2,3}/{a,b,c}/yy/data; do mkdir -p "$d"; done`.

Comment: What about simply `mkdir -p /tmp/{1,2,3}/{a,b,c}/yy/data` ?

Comment: Your definition of DATA_L1 does not make much sense. This would just expand to `/tmp/{1,2,3}`, but tince applying the comma occurs earlier than the parameter expansion, this does NOT expand to /tmp/1 /tmp/2 /tmp/3, as you might have hoped.

Comment: @chepner: i expected resolutoin of variables in $LINE to be done recursivelly and brace expansion to happen during mkdir call.

Comment: @user1934428: it makes sense because of the logic later. this L1 thing is also passed as a parameter, so this 1,2,3.

Comment: @oliv: generally yes, but in this setup i cannot use it since yy/data is not a single line that gets returned by "cat", therefore the loop. and the values returned by "cat" contain the bash variable... ah, i should just rewrite everything here.

Comment: Note that `for line in $(cat yourfile)` is inherently buggy, as described in [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Use `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done <yourfile` (as described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that you have **two** layers of expansion, even though you don't show that in your question.  That is, you show:

```
mkdir -pv $DATA_L2/yy/data
```

And this would work if you simply added an `eval` to it:

```
eval mkdir -pv $DATA_L2/yy/data
```

But inside your loop, you're not actually running the above command.  I think you're running something like:

```
mkdir -pv $LINE
```

If we stick an `echo` in front of that `mkdir`, we can see that:

```
echo mkdir -pv $LINE
```

Results in:

```
mkdir -pv $DATA_L2/yy/data
```

And:

```
eval echo mkdir -pv $LINE
```

Results in:

```
mkdir -pv /tmp/{1,2,3}/{a,b,c}/yy/data
```

If you *double* the eval:

```
eval eval echo mkdir -pv $LINE
```

You get what you are looking for:

```
mkdir -pv /tmp/1/a/yy/data /tmp/1/b/yy/data /tmp/1/c/yy/data /tmp/2/a/yy/data /tmp/2/b/yy/data /tmp/2/c/yy/data /tmp/3/a/yy/data /tmp/3/b/yy/data /tmp/3/c/yy/data
```

But a double `eval` is a really good sign that need to rethink your approach to the problem.

Comment: there is also $LINE there. i left it out by mistake. will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Your edits match my assumptions, so this answer still applies. I suspect that @wjandrea is on the right track w/r/t rethinking your approach to the problem.

Comment: this is actually what i was looking for. this "double" eval that you used italic on solved the issue. even though it is possibly xy problem, i do not think so. i actually want to avoid using loops and substitute it with brace expansion. loops are there already...

Comment: You only need a double eval because you aren't quoting correctly in your single-eval approach. `eval "mkdir -pv $LINE"` with the quotes behaves properly.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/343832), but one option may be arrays and for loops, similar to this:

```
numbers=(1 2 3)
letters=(a b c)

dir="/tmp"

for letter in "${letters[@]}"; do
    for number in "${numbers[@]}"; do
        echo mkdir -pv "$dir/$number/$letter/yy/data"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
mkdir -pv /tmp/1/a/yy/data
mkdir -pv /tmp/2/a/yy/data
mkdir -pv /tmp/3/a/yy/data
mkdir -pv /tmp/1/b/yy/data
mkdir -pv /tmp/2/b/yy/data
mkdir -pv /tmp/3/b/yy/data
mkdir -pv /tmp/1/c/yy/data
mkdir -pv /tmp/2/c/yy/data
mkdir -pv /tmp/3/c/yy/data
```

Comment: i do not think that the question is xy problem. the actual need is to create those directories without making any loops, aka use brace expansion. for some reason every combination i have tried (due to complex structure) didnt work and due to nature of the work, i do not feel comfortable posting the full script here (legal resons).

Comment: @mispp In that case, make a [mre] and give your constraints explicitly.

Comment: fair enough. i will look into this a bit later since i have to continue working on other issues. thank you both for solutions here.

Comment: @mispp, consider `IFS=, read -r -a numbers <<<"$numbers_str"` if you have something like `numbers_str="1,2,3"` as input and want to get `numbers=( 1 2 3 )` as given in this answer.