# Bash Script to create directories and sub directories with variable inputs not working

Tags: bash, automator

Using automator I have created a script asking for variable input, it then uses the variables to create directories and sub directories. I am stuck on one part.

```
mkdir "$1/$2"
cd "$1/$2"
mkdir -p {010421,011121,011821,012521,020121,020821,021521,022221,030121,030821,031521,032221,032921,040521,041221,041921,042621,050321,051021,051721,052421,053121,060721,061421,062121,062821,070521,071221,071921,072621,080221,080921,081621,082321,083021,090621,091321,092021,092721,100421,101121,101821,102521,110121,110821,111521,112221,112921,120621,121321,122021,122721}/{_AD_info/"$3",_HR,_LR}
```

Variable $3 at the end is where I am stuck. This variable is input from the user and would look something like this "A1,A2,A3,A4", which in theory should create sub directories for each inside the directory "_Ad_info". But when I run the script it is creating one directory named "A1,A2,A3,A4", no separate directories.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with Apple's Automator tool?

Comment: Anyhow -- I'd suggest (1) reducing the example to be more readable (no reason to hardcode tens of identifiers when two will do); and (2) showing exactly what directories are being created, and exactly what directories you _want_ to be created (f/e, via the output of a `find . -type d` command on an otherwise-empty directory where your command has been run).

Comment: I am using automator to ask for the variables, I didnt know if that would effect the variable input in the bash script. So I just wanted to clarify how I was using it. Sorry if I was vague.

Comment: Gotcha. To find out if there _is_ any problem caused by Automator, I'd suggest something like this: `{ echo "Command line arguments:"; printf ' - %q\n' "$@"; } >&2` to print your command-line arguments. If they have the expected values, then we know that they're being passed in correctly and can factor out that part of the question.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/SjDkp6 showing your script being run, and the list of arguments it passes to `mkdir`. Does that list of arguments differ from the directories you _want_ it to create? (Note that the backslashes are just reflecting that the spaces are literal, not syntactic; they're not part of the directory names themselves).

Comment: Also -- if you don't have a shebang, it'd be better to add one. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the very first line will make sure your script is run _by bash_, as opposed to by `sh` or some other interpreter. (If `printf %q` gives an error, that makes it basically certain that your script is being run by a non-bash shell).

Comment: Oh, wait -- you have commas **in the variable**? Yeah, that won't work. Those commas are literal, not syntactic. (If bash treated data as if it were syntax, it would be impossible to write secure code handling untrusted data in it; in the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478499/bash-brace-expansion-based-on-variable-content-not-working), note that any answer that tells you to use `eval` is doing something deliberately insecure -- [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) describes why).

Comment: Thanks, it is the commas in the variable that are giving me the issue, I am not sure how I can create sub directories from comma separated variables or if it is even possible. I appreciate the help, I am new to scripting and this site so please bear with me.

Comment: See the linked duplicate, where this question was asked and answered previously. (I don't personally recommend the accepted answer there -- using `eval` is bad, doubling `eval` is even worse, and not quoting your `eval` arguments adds extra potential for bugs -- but it's where we have answers to the question of how to use a variable in a brace expansion; and that accepted answer isn't the _only_ available answer).